# Javascript section of html form is not running

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have created a html form and have added a Javascript section to it to display a "Submission Successful" message. However, the Javascript section does not seem to do anything but the form is operating normally. I have tried moving the script part to different sections and have tried to running different things as tests but nothing is running. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  margin: 50;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 60px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #3585CC;
  border-color: #3585CC;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #346FA4;
  border-color: #346FA4;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.label {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.form-control:focus {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.success-message {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: green;
  visibility: hidden;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="header">
    Contact Form
  </h1>
  <form action="/form" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name_Person">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name_Person" name="Name_Person" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PNumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="PNumber" name="PNumber" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" onclick=Successmessageup()>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div id="success" class="success-message">
    <strong>Submission Successful!</strong> Your message has been sent.
  </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Successmessageup(){
  document.getElementById('success-message').style.visibility = 'visible';
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that there may be some bad practice in this form. This is just a a simple form to get the Javascript part working. I am new to html so I feel like I am making a simple mistake that is causing this.

Comment: `document.getElementById('success-message')` but you have `<div id="success" class="success-message">`

Comment: Also note that hitting the submit button will leave the current page and navigate to `/form`. The message will only be shown very briefly (if at all) while the `/form` page is loading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add JS library for executing the script and also can use form submit() function to submit the form.

```js
$(function () {
        
     $('#send_message_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById('success-message').style.visibility = 'visible';
       //you can write form submit logic here
      });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  margin: 50;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 60px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #3585CC;
  border-color: #3585CC;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #346FA4;
  border-color: #346FA4;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.label {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.form-control:focus {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.success-message {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: green;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="header">
    Contact Form
  </h1>
  <form name="send_message_form" id="send_message_form" class="was-validated" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name_Person">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name_Person" name="Name_Person" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="PNumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="PNumber" name="PNumber" placeholder="Enter your phone number" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div id="success-message" class="success-message">
    <strong>Submission Successful!</strong> Your message has been sent.
  </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Successmessageup(){
  document.getElementById('success-message').style.visibility = 'visible';
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @PreolanN, any issue with my code?

Comment: If you want to use your code then you have to add JS library and need to change id of the  success div like this:  <div id="success-message" class="success-message">
    <strong>Submission Successful!</strong> Your message has been sent.
  </div>

Comment: There is no need to introduce jQuery just to prevent the form submission. That is easily achievable just with vanilla JS. Also I doubt that OP wants to prevent the form submission. That would defeat the main purpose of the form.